# how to send a variable to another page using ajax and mootools?

Tags: ajax, post, mootools

i am trying to send a variable to another page with a post request and i use this:

```
var x="hello";

var sender=new Request({
          url:"page.html",
          method:"post",
          data:x
       });
sender.send();
```

but how do i colected x after it gets sent to page.html? i tried reading everything i could find and work it out myself but i get strange results, so if anyone could give me a simple example i would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle example (using the echo service to simulate a response)

http://www.jsfiddle.net/BVgNt/1/

```
var x = "bar";
new Request.HTML({
    url: '/echo/html/',
    data: {
        x: "bar",
        html: "x was '" + x + "'",
        delay: 0
    },
    method: 'post',
    onComplete: function() {
        console.log(this.response.text);
        document.id("target").set("html", this.response.text);
    }
}).send();
```

the idea in the request class is that it fires an onComplete (onSuccess and onError too) events when done, with `this.response` containing various collections of responses, check that in the firebug console to see what you can extract or consult the mootools Request.HTML manual.

Comment: you dont undersstand, i want to know how to colect x, you know? sending it from one page to another but using only js i know how to do it with php on the server but i dont want that

Comment: when you send it to the other page then it will produce a resulting html, this allows you to parse the html and extract it back within the onComplete event.

Comment: another thing that will be helpful is you providing the bit of html that comes back, in particular some reasonable code blocks that output that variable, eg `<div id="foo"><?=$_POST['x']?></div>`